# How can I generate a PDF automatically using itext in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a Windows Form App which automatically generates a PDF using itext. I was using the following code previously to generate the PDF:

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("C:/Users/bra/800C.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();

        document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);                             

        Paragraph p17 = new Paragraph("Use formulations of Penzien (2000) assuming full slip condition. ");
        document.Add(p17);

        document.Close();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way that my code could be modified so that the PDF can be opened automatically when the program is run? (Rather than being saved on the C drive)? I have seen some examples with memoryStream online but couldn't wrap my head around how this works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would check the Windows 10 UAC setting first. Don't know if it is related to the error, but it is one of the first things I would do.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it did not help though :(

Comment: By default Windows 10 won't allow non-administrators to create files or folders in the root of the system drive. Try running the app as administrator or choose a different location

Comment: Hi, I tried both to these but it didn't work. Is there no way just to get the PDF to open automatically when the program is run, thus eliminating the issue of access priveledges?

Comment: You want to open it, but open it in what? If in Adobe Acrobat Reader, then you need the PDF as file. If in some other viewer or viewer component of your program, the situation may differ.